# Angular básico, problema no reconoce initViz

Tags: angular

Perdonar mi ignorancia pero estoy iniciándome en Angular y tengo un problema con mi primera aplicación.
Ha funcionado sin problemas hasta que llegado un momento, sin que sea consciente de haber cambiado nada, obtengo el error de la imagen, que me impide ejecutar ng serve.

!https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AEXZuyyzK1m6K9_zEdz9zr7y8LfklyZD/view

Para más extrañeza mía si comento la linea ejecuto ng serve y una vez arrancado el navegador descomento la linea que tiene el error todo funciona igual que antes.

He pasado el codigo a stackblitz y espero que me podais ayudar.
Gracias por adelantado.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-initviz

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: El código y las imágenes pueden ir directo en la pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que initViz() es una función que no se encuentra declarada. Debes crear esta función dentro del scope del componente para poder utilizarla. 
Una vez creada esta función la forma correcta de llamarla es:

```
this.initViz(this.opcionSeleccionada)
```